# Convert melted df with custom dates to a time-series

Tags: r, time-series

I've got a `df` in the long format (obtained through `melt`), with a column `date` containing month and a year. It looks like this:

```
 state  value  date 
 tex    0.2    01.2012
 tex    0.3    02.2012 
 tex    0.1    03.2012
 ny     0.5    01.2012
 ny     0.4    02.2012 
 ny     0.2    03.2012
```

I would like to convert this `df` to a time-series object, keeping it in the long format.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it month -year format

Comment: Hi @akrun, yes it is!

Comment: A wide form zoo object would be: `library(zoo);
to_ym <- function(x) as.yearmon(as.character(x), format = "%m.%Y");
z <- read.zoo(DF, index = "date", FUN = to_ym, split = "state")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `tsibble`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(date = as.Date(str_c('01.', date), '%d.%m.%Y')) %>% 
   as_tsibble(key = state, index = date)
```

-output

```
# A tsibble: 6 x 3 [1D]
# Key:       state [2]
#  state value date      
#  <chr> <dbl> <date>    
#1 ny      0.5 2012-01-01
#2 ny      0.4 2012-02-01
#3 ny      0.2 2012-03-01
#4 tex     0.2 2012-01-01
#5 tex     0.3 2012-02-01
#6 tex     0.1 2012-03-01
```

---

If we need to add the grouping attribute, use `group_by_key`

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(str_c('01.', date), '%d.%m.%Y')) %>% 
    as_tsibble(key = state, index = date) %>%
    group_by_key()
# A tsibble: 6 x 3 [1D]
# Key:       state [2]
# Groups:    state [2]
#  state value date      
#  <chr> <dbl> <date>    
#1 ny      0.5 2012-01-01
#2 ny      0.4 2012-02-01
#3 ny      0.2 2012-03-01
#4 tex     0.2 2012-01-01
#5 tex     0.3 2012-02-01
#6 tex     0.1 2012-03-01
```

---

Or another option is to `split` by 'state' and then convert to `xts` object

```
library(xts)
library(zoo)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
 group_split(state) %>% 
 map(~ xts(.x$value, order.by = as.yearmon(.x$date, '%m.%Y')))
#[[1]]
#         [,1]
#Jan 2012  0.5
#Feb 2012  0.4
#Mar 2012  0.2

#[[2]]
#         [,1]
#Jan 2012  0.2
#Feb 2012  0.3
#Mar 2012  0.1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(state = c("tex", "tex", "tex", "ny", "ny", "ny"
), value = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2), date = c("01.2012", 
"02.2012", "03.2012", "01.2012", "02.2012", "03.2012")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you :) Just a question - does the time series column always have to have day/month/year? Can't it just be month/year?

Comment: @fifigoblin You could convert to `yearmon` from `zoo`, but the issue is that it is not supported in `tsibble` `Error: No index support for class "yearmon".`

Comment: Thanks! I saw your edit - could I ask, if I wanted to then calculate mean value in January (01) for each `state` can I use `summarise`?

Comment: @fifigoblin you could convert to `tibble` and do the group by mean i.e. `..%>% as_tibble %>% group_by(state) %>% summarise(value = mean(value))`